# Making an Array call an object in and index

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios6

I am getting error that myArray hides an instances variable. Please explain briefly what the error means and how to fix it. Thanks for you help. I am new at programming with objective-c

```
- (IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *snarkyCommentArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Butter",@"Cheese",@"Gravy",@"Your fat",@"smells like roses",nil];


    self.snarkOffLabel.text = [snarkyCommentArray objectAtIndex:(1)];

}
@end
```

Comment: Your question is about `myArray` but the code you posted makes no reference to such an array.

Comment: The array (myArray) must be declared in the header file, and you should have also in the .m something like :
NSArray *myArray = ...
You are using myArray again, but not the same one, but with the same name...

I you want to keep it in the .h, and use it everywhere in your code, you'd do : myArray = ... If it's only for local use, erase it from the header file and write : NSArray *myArray =...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say, your ivar and local variable have same name. So you need to change the name of either one. Or use arrow operator to access your ivar.

Answer (score 0):

While the code doesn't align with your question, I can still explain the error message.

If your class defines an instance variable, and you then create a local variable with the same name, the compiler warns you that the local variable will be used and not the instance variable. The local variable is "hiding" the instance variable.

It's best to ensure that you never give local variables the same name as instance variables to avoid any confusion. A common practice is to give all of your instance variables an underscore prefix such as `_myArray`. This way, whenever you are reading code, it's very obvious which variables are instance variables and which are not.

Another way to avoid the issue is to reference instance variables through the `self` pointer.

Let's say my class has a instance variable named `foo` and I have a local variable named `foo`.

```
foo = 5; // local variable
self->foo = 10; // instance variable
```

Comment: I got this problems sorted. Thanks for you help Everyone. I changed the global variable's name and stuck with useing the "snarkyCommentArray" locally. No more fizzle.

Comment: @JonSchaller Don't forget to accept an answer. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject{
NSString *name;
}

- (void)print:(NSString*)name;
- (void)printName;
@end

@implementation myClass

- (void)print:(NSString*)name{
    // This line will print the local variable 'name', not the instance variable 'name'
    // This line will cause a warning to the effect "Local variable hides instance variable"

    NSLog(@"%@", name);
}

- (void)print{
    // This line will print the instance variable 'name'.
    NSLog(@"%@", name);

    NSString *name = @"Steve";

    // This line will print the local variable 'name'.
    // This line will cause a warning to the effect "Local variable hides instance variable"
    NSLog(@"%@", name);
}
@end
```

It's important to understand the difference between instance variables and local variables. An instance variable is a variable defined in your class's '@interface' section. Example:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {
// Instance variables
NSString *name;
float progressAmount;
NSUInteger *age;
}
@end
```

An instance variable can be accessed by any method of the class.  A local variable is a variable that has local scope and can only be accessed in the method or block in which it is declared. Example:

```
- (int)square:(int)num{
    int result = num * num;
    return result;
}
```

In the preceding example both `num` and `result` are local variables. The `square:` method is their entire universe. They can't be accessed from outside of `square:` nor do they exist once `square:` returns. They are said to have local scope.

So what happens when an instance variable and a local variable are given the same name? It all comes down to scope. Local variables trump instance variables when it comes to scope, so when faced with the decision of which variable to use, the compiler will use the local variable. This is why the compiler produces a warning and not an error. What is happening is perfectly acceptable, but it's still a good idea to warn the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try check where is mistake with `NSLog`?  Do u know about if `snarkyCommentArray` keeps your strings?  Check it like

```
Nslog(@"snarkyCommentArray %@",snarkyCommentArray);
```

if it keeps all, then care about your label,  you can use it without `self` like

```
snarkOffLabel.text = [snarkyCommentArray objectAtIndex:(1)];
```

if it still doesn't work, then allocate your array like `NSMutableArray`,

```
NSMutableArray *snarkyCommentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Butter",@"Cheese",@"Gravy",@"Your fat",@"smells like roses",nil];
```

Hope it helps.